# How to edit a pasted row automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code that duplicates (copies and pastes) a selected row to the bottom of a table. But I am struggling to add more functions to this code.

After pasting the row into the bottom of the list, I need that:

1. The row background is coloured with # fff2cc
2. The first cell updates to today's date
3. The content of the cell on column K is deleted

The code I have currently returns the error, "spreadsheet is not defined", but I'm struggling to correct it.

```
function Reschedule() {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var sheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var row = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  var dst = sheet.getRange(row, 1);
  activeRange.offset(0, 0, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

//the above code works perfectly to copy the selected row and paste it on the bottom of the list, but I need to adjust the code below to make it work with the above. 

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow(), 1, 1, 
  sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#fff2cc');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(date);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 10).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Does anybody know if it is possible? I'm open to other alternatives as well.

Comment: Looks you have a "spreadsheet" variable that is being used but isn't ever created. In general, that kind of "'variable name' is not defined" error means that there is something being used (read from, written to...) that does not exist. If you resolve that, how is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the last part with this code that does your desired steps in your proposed order:

```
function Reschedule() {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var sheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var row = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  var dst = sheet.getRange(row, 1);
  activeRange.offset(0, 0, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

//the above code works perfectly to copy the selected row and paste it on the bottom of the list, but I need to adjust the code below to make it work with the above. 
  sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#fff2cc")
  sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date())
  sheet.getRange(row,11).clearContent()
};
```